# GFCI and AFCI outlet on circuit with refrigerator ....tripping after 6-8 hours after reset

Tags: gfci, afci

Initially had a freezer and refrigerator freezer in garage on GFCI circuit, no problems for years.  Then the freezer went out and the gfci circuit outlet was apparently damaged (and was 20 years old anyway). It would not stay on after that even with freezer unplugged.

Replaced gfci outlet with new gfci / afci combo outlet.  With only the 20-year-old refrigerator freezer on that circuit...the combo outlet trip every 6-8 hours (a guess, but do know that the refrig./freezer stays very cold) before I check it and find out it is off again.   Thus, that refrigerator/freezer had been on that circuit for years with no problems until ...the above noted circumstances.

- Can the afci cause this?
- If it is something about the defrost element oxidizing and a little leakage current at defrost shutting it down, then why would the prior gfci outlet not have caused this?
- Would the afci portion make the difference?
- If so, how can this be confirmed?  and is a little leakage current common in those situations.......and is it dangerous?

BUT FIRST, HOW TO KNOW WHAT IS REALLY GOING ON HERE???

Comment: Does it have any ability to indicate whether it is tripping for AFCI vs GFCI?  Some have indicators; check your docs.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally considered a bad idea to have refrigerators on a GFCI circuit, especially if the outlet isn't the only thing on the line to the circuit breaker box.

> Why is it bad if the refrigerator is on a GFCI circuit?
> A GFCI trips when the outgoing and returning current differ. The startup of the compressor within the refrigerator can cause minor spikes in the flow of electricity, causing the GFCI breaker to shut off power to the outlet.
>
> Another reason why a refrigerator or freezer should not be on a GFCI outlet is because GFCI outlets are often “daisy chained.” This means that one GFCI circuit can be connected to multiple outlets in the kitchen or garage. There is the possibility that another outlet could inadvertently trip the GFCI circuit, thus causing a power loss to the refrigerator/freezer.
>
> In any scenario, with a GFCI outlet connected to a GFCI circuit, there is a high chance for an inadvertent power loss to the appliance. With the loss of electricity to a refrigerator or freezer, the contents of the refrigerator and freezer will quickly begin to thaw and spoil. If this is discovered by the home inspector, it is a good idea to have a licensed electrician repair the deficiency and eliminate the potential risk of food spoilage.
>
> — [Dwell Inspect Arizona - The home inspector found a refrigerator/freezer on a GFCI circuit](https://dwellinspectaz.com/dwell-inspect-arizona-blog/fridge-gfci)

I think the takeaway is that any benefit that a GFCI might provide (almost none for a refrigerator) is far outweighed by the much more likely event that the food will spoil (and then possibly refreeze without anyone's being aware that the event has happened).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a fault that has developed in your fridge/freezer.  I think you need an electrician to confirm it for you.  Or maybe call a whiteware service guy to have a look at it.

Comment: This just an opinion, but you might be getting what call here as "Nuisance trips".   That's when the GFCI or AFCI outlet trips for minor, not dangerous fault, esp. if the equipment is properly grounded.  It may take a bit of research and testing to be sure that nothing more serious is going on. If it turns out nothing bad is happening, it's code legal to replace the recalcitrant GFCI with a normal one.

Comment: Refrigerators, I'm told, are somewhat notorious for nuisance trips.

Comment: @keshlam Refrigerators have often been accused of causing nuisance trips on GFCI, but I've never heard of one nuisiance-tripping an AFCI.  This one might be a legit problem w/the appliance.  In this case being a combo unit, though, it's even harder to diagnose.

Comment: Granted. Though I could see, eg, a sparking compressor motor upsetting an AFCI.

Answer (score 0):

Most fridges have something called defrost cycle.  During the automatic defrost cycle, heat rises up from the **defrost heater** to melt the ice on the evaporator coils for a set amount of time.

The automatic defrost cycle generally runs every 8 hours depending on the model and it lasts for approximately 30 minutes. The compressor does not run during that time.

I would say your defrost heating element has a short and triggers the AFCI but not the GFCI, since it is not Ground Faullt